# How to get all pages included in different years with the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: python, web-scraping, stackexchange-api

I would like to get all the questions and comments with a particular tag contained on the Stack Overflow site.
With the use of [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/), I managed to make a simple call but I would like to know how I could scroll through the pages to get all the data even from different years.

I'm trying to do that with questions tagged `python`.
For example, this link returns all questions from 1st July, 2019 to 5th July, 2019 with tag python:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?fromdate=1561939200&todate=1562284800&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow
```

But if I wanted all data from 2015 to 2019, could I include a code like this one?

```
?page=10
```

Where could I put it?

Comment: Convert those dates into unix timestamps and replace `fromdate` and `todate` with them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[There are 845 thousand python questions, from 2015 to 2019](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2015-01-01&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&filter=!w-*Ytm8YGWVl9..xoC&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (so far).
That's 8,454 ***pages*** of API requests -- which is dangerously close to your [max quota](https://stackapps.com/questions/6961/how-to-increase-app-request-quota-from-300-to-10-000).
Additionally, trying to fetch that many pages at once is likely to trigger [throttling](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) or [bugs](https://stackapps.com/questions/8356/after-successfully-retrieving-180-pages-the-api-gracelessly-semi-silently-fai).

So, it **would be better** if you downloaded [the *Data Dump*](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), or ran paged queries against [the *Stack Exchange Data Explorer* (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) **for the bulk of your data**.  Then just use the API to get the changes since the last dump or SEDE update.

Both subjects that are beyond scope for this question. (And also addressed before in other posts).

To answer your direct question, you would page through the results like so:

1. ***Fetch:*** [2.2/questions?**page=1**&pagesize=100&fromdate=1420070400&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=2015-01-01&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&filter=!6xGkKBjMFEsggJ0Seh_gbZnVfTKAxgCS_IVRY0cFg50-_04tCyYpv.ns(Q2Rlkqpt_M2n&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
2. ***Then:*** [2.2/questions?**page=2**&pagesize=100&fromdate=1420070400&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=2&pagesize=100&fromdate=2015-01-01&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&filter=!6xGkKBjMFEsggJ0Seh_gbZnVfTKAxgCS_IVRY0cFg50-_04tCyYpv.ns(Q2Rlkqpt_M2n&site=stackoverflow&run=true)
3. etc.
4. You can also loop until [`has_more`<sup>(Doc)</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) is `false`.